# OData POST doesn't set last property of object using a Asp.Net ApiController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata

I have the following xml document, which is submitted ( POST ) with an System.Web.Http.ApiController.

The code of the controller ( POST ) is pretty basic:

```
   <ResponseType(GetType(Representative))>
    Function PostRepresentative(ByVal model As Representative) As IHttpActionResult
        If Not ModelState.IsValid Then
            Return BadRequest(ModelState)
        End If

        RepresentativeRepository.Add(model)
        UnitOfWork.Commit()
        '   db.Representative.Add(Representative)
        '   db.SaveChangesAsync()

        Return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", New With {.id = model.Id}, model)
    End Function
```

And here is the document i'm submitting in the POST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Representative xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Omnisoft.Domain.Slave" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <Id>8</Id>
     <Commission>10</Commission>
     <Email />
     <receiveInvoice>true</receiveInvoice>
     <receiveDeliveryNotice>true</receiveDeliveryNotice>
     <receiveEstimate>true</receiveEstimate>
     <receiveOrderConfirmation>true</receiveOrderConfirmation>
     <receiveRappel>true</receiveRappel>
     <receiveCollectedBilling>true</receiveCollectedBilling>
     <receiveWorkOrder>false</receiveWorkOrder>
     <Name>TESTING</Name>
</Representative>
```

This is my corresponding model:

```
 Public Class Representative
    <Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)> _
    Public Property Id As Integer

    Public Property Name As String

    <LocalizedDisplayName("Commission", NameResourceType:=GetType(ViewRes.RepresentativeValue))>
    Public Property Commission As Double

    <DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)> _
    Public Property Email As String

    Public Property receiveEstimate As Boolean
    Public Property receiveOrderConfirmation As Boolean
    Public Property receiveDeliveryNotice As Boolean
    Public Property receiveInvoice As Boolean
    Public Property receiveCollectedBilling As Boolean
    Public Property receiveWorkOrder As Boolean
    Public Property receiveRappel As Boolean

End Class
```

When the xml document puts Name as the last property, it doesn't get submitted in the model. When it's submitted at the top of the XML file. Odata can "parse/serialize" the property and there is no problem.

Otherwhise, my added entity contains a nil value for Name.

Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because -- don't have the code anymore that is requested. I just remembered the answer that my first serializer didn't achieve good results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used a different xml serializer and that worked.

Comment: Which one? Can you be specific? Maybe even add a code example. This answer is nothing more than a non-constructive comment as it stands now.

Comment: A bit late, but there are only 2 in the dotnet framework. Xml Serializer vs the DataContracts serializer :)